# Очистить html-код от текста Jquery / js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(function() {
  var takeHtml = $('#take').get(0).outerHTML;
  /*удаляем из takeHtml весь текст кроме тегов*/
  alert(takeHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="take">
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Результат должен быть таким:

```
<tr id="take">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Вам чисто для этого кода, или универсальный для любых тегов и любой вложенности?

Comment: может так  $("#take").children("td").each(function(){ $(this).text("") })

Comment: Универсальный, если можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var takeHtml = $('#take').get(0).outerHTML;
  /* удаляем содержимое тегов */
  takeHtml = takeHtml.replace(/>[^><](.+?)</g,"><");
  alert(takeHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="take">
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

как хотите, так применяйте

```js
$(function() {
  $('#take td').html('');
  var takeHtml = $('#take').get(0).outerHTML;
  /*удаляем из takeHtml весь текст кроме тегов*/
  alert(takeHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
      <th>Zag1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
      <td>QWER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="take">
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
      <td>QWER1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```